# Provide local currency format i18n on server and process is on client

Tags: javascript, rest, localization, internationalization, locale

We need to display the amounts/numbers in different formats based on user's locale. The information is provided though a REST API.

```
fr = 1 234 567,89
en-us = 1,234,567.89
de = 1.234.567,89
```

One way is to process it fully on the server-side. Another way is to process it fully on the client-side using a library such dojo/i18n .

However I'm wondering if it's possible to provide somehow the number format (the format only not the number itself) through the API and then format the number on the client-side (using javascript). Any idea how that can be done ? I mean how the "format" should look like and how it can be rendered/processed so that it can be used as a pattern to format the number on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Many javascript frameworks have localized formatters for dates and numbers. Usually the formats are static, so you could hardcode them in a config.js. And if that isn't enough you can render them in the config.js on the server. You could even localize that resource server side to reduce the amount of code sent over the wire.

You could also provide an API where you can GET the format for the clients locale, but that seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). It can be done, all you have to do is define (or override) the culture. Take a look at [French culture file](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.fr.js) to see how it can be done:

```
Globalize.addCultureInfo( "fr", "default", {
// (...)
    numberFormat: {
        ",": " ",
        ".": ",",
        "NaN": "Non Numérique",
        negativeInfinity: "-Infini",
        positiveInfinity: "+Infini",
        percent: {
            ",": " ",
            ".": ","
        },
        currency: {
        pattern: ["-n $","n $"],
            ",": " ",
            ".": ",",
        symbol: "€"
    }
// (...)
```

Depending on the source of your format, you might need to transform the data to something understandable by Globalize, but yes, it can be done.